# Getting NullPointerException while running a Cucumber test with Spring Boot, Selenium and JUnit

Tags: spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have a simple `Selenium-Cucumber` based test that is throwing `NullPointerException` when I am executing it.

I have already initialized the `WebDriver (chrome)` but for some reason the test is not able to pick that.

Not sure why driver is not getting initialized even after doing a `new` on `ChromeDriver`

**Error**

```
com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.example.TestRunner
driver: null

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.GoogleCalcStepDefinition.I_open_google(GoogleCalcStepDefinition.java:38)
    at ✽.I open Google(file:src/test/resources/features/calc.feature:7)

Feature: Check addition in Google calculatorcontent
  In order to verify that Google calculator work correctly
  As a user of Google
  I should be able to get correct addition result

  Scenario: Addition                     # src/test/resources/features/calc.feature:6
    Given I open Google                  # GoogleCalcStepDefinition.I_open_google()
      java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.GoogleCalcStepDefinition.I_open_google(GoogleCalcStepDefinition.java:38)
    at ✽.I open Google(file:src/test/resources/features/calc.feature:7)

    When I enter "2+2" in search textbox # GoogleCalcStepDefinition.I_enter_in_search_textbox(String)
    Then I should get result as "4"      # GoogleCalcStepDefinition.I_should_get_correct_result(String)

Failed scenarios:
src/test/resources/features/calc.feature:6 # Addition

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
3 Steps (1 failed, 2 skipped)
0m1.364s

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.GoogleCalcStepDefinition.I_open_google(GoogleCalcStepDefinition.java:38)
    at ✽.I open Google(file:src/test/resources/features/calc.feature:7)
```

**GoogleCalcStepDefinition.java**

```
public class GoogleCalcStepDefinition extends CucumberStepDefinitions {

    private static final String CHROME_DRIVER_EXE = "drivers/chromedriver.exe";
    private static final String WEBDRIVER_CHROME_DRIVER = "webdriver.chrome.driver";
    private static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        System.out.println("Into the setUp() method...");
        String filePath = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(CHROME_DRIVER_EXE).getFile();
        System.setProperty(WEBDRIVER_CHROME_DRIVER, filePath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }

    @Given("^I open Google$")
    public void I_open_google() {
        System.out.println("driver: " + driver);
        //Set implicit wait of 10 seconds and launch google
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
    }

    @When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" in search textbox$")
    public void I_enter_in_search_textbox(String additionTerms) {
        //Write term in google textbox
        WebElement googleTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq"));
        googleTextBox.sendKeys(additionTerms);

        //Click on searchButton
        WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb"));
        searchButton.click();
    }

    @Then("^I should get result as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_should_get_correct_result(String expectedResult) {
        //Get result from calculator
        WebElement calculatorTextBox = driver.findElement(By.id("cwos"));
        String result = calculatorTextBox.getText();
        //Verify that result of 2+2 is 4
        assertEquals(result, expectedResult);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void closeBrowser() {
        if (null != driver) {
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

**CucumberStepDefinitions.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public abstract class CucumberStepDefinitions {

}
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty"}, features = {"src/test/resources/features"})
public class TestRunner {

}
```

**src/test/resources/features/calc.feature**

```
Feature: Check addition in Google calculatorcontent
  In order to verify that Google calculator work correctly
  As a user of Google
  I should be able to get correct addition result

  Scenario: Addition
    Given I open Google
    When I enter "2+2" in search textbox
    Then I should get result as "4"
```

**src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe**

**pom.xml**

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.45.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I don 't see the output of `System.out.println("Into the setUp() method...");` in the console. Are you sure this method was invoked?

Comment: Did you import `@BeforeClass` from `JUnit` package?

Comment: @Fenio - Yes, I did. Without them being imported the code would not have even compiled. It looks like `Cucumber` cannot identify `JUnit` annotations and it completely ignores it.

Comment: That was actually what I was in mind. You can use `cucumber.api.Before` to instantiate WebDriver per Scenario :)

Comment: Bull's eye :). That worked like a charm. Kind of new to Cucumber and didn't knew they had these cool annotations that I could use instead of JUnit annotations.

Comment: You can also pass the argument `order` for `@Before` and `@After` annotations. Example: `@Before(order = 1)` :)

Comment: I added the answer for future readers

Comment: Thanks and I upvoted it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you used JUnit's `@BeforeClass` annotation which is not respected by Cucumber runner.

Instead, you can use `cucumber.api.Before` -> `@Before` or `@After` annotations.

If you annotate method hook with one of these annotations you can use `Scenario` interface to get, for example, tags of the running scenario.

You can also have multiple `@Before` and `@After` methods and you can provide order of them like this:

```
@Before(order = 1)
public void init(Scenario scenario) { }
```

Comment: Ok, so does that mean that you can have multiple methods annotated in the same class with `@Before` and prioritize the execution using `order` argument. Moreover is `@Before (cucumber.api.Before)` same as `@BeforeClass (org.junit.BeforeClass)` ?

Comment: @user2325154 Yes, exactly. Just make sure to watch for the order. Because for `@Before` lower numbers are run first. For the `@After` higher number are run first.

additionaly, make sure that these hooks are available to Cucumber Runner just like Cucumber Steps.

Comment: Ok, so one of the requirements of `JUnit @BeforeClass` is that the method should be `static`. Does the same thing applies to `Cucumber's @Before` as well ?

Comment: @user2325154 No, the methods are `public void myHookName(Scenario scenario)`